# Error in loading drupal website call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, drupal-6

I'm trying to load my Drupal (6) website and I got this message:

> warning: call_user_func_array()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '_print_mail_access' not found or invalid function name in C:\wamp\www\mysite\includes\menu.inc on line 454.

The line 454 is in this function:

```
function ctools_menu_get_active_help() {
  $output = '';
  $router_path = ctools_menu_tab_root_path();
  // We will always have a path unless we are on a 403 or 404.
  if (!$router_path) {
    return '';
  }

  $arg = drupal_help_arg(arg(NULL));
  $empty_arg = drupal_help_arg();

  foreach (module_list() as $name) {
    if (module_hook($name, 'help')) {
      // Lookup help for this path.
      if ($help = module_invoke($name, 'help', $router_path, $arg)) {
        $output .= $help ."\n";
      }
      // Add "more help" link on admin pages if the module provides a
      // standalone help page.
      if ($arg[0] == "admin" && module_exists('help') && module_invoke($name, 'help', 'admin/help#'. $arg[2], $empty_arg) && $help) {
        $output .= theme("more_help_link", url('admin/help/'. $arg[2]));
      }
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are talking something strange. First of all, Drupal 8 (your tag) doesn't contain `includes\menu.inc` directory and file. Drupal 7 has such file, but on the line #454 there is an end of comment... Then, `CTools` module doesn't contain `ctools_menu_get_active_help()` function neither in D7 nor in D8 version... :)

Comment: sorry its for D6 !!!

Comment: Where is the function `_print_mail_access` defined?

Comment: it is in print.module ! i solved it by just adding the module manually. thanks all.